# Optimise a function that calls itself in Obj C

Tags: objective-c, function

I've written a function that checks whether a live score has changed every 0.1 seconds, and if it has it plays a system sound on iPhone.

```
- (void) checkIfShouldHaptic {
    loadedScore = [self loadScoreFromKey:keyScore];            //load score saved in key
    controllerScore = [self checkCurrentScore];                //check current score

    if (loadedScore < controllerScore){                        //if score in key is less than controller score
        [self saveScore:controllerScore];                      //save new score in key
        AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);  //play system sound
        [self repeatCheckIfShouldHaptic];                      //repeat
    }
    else {                                                     //else score is not less
        [self repeatCheckIfShouldHaptic];                      //repeat
   }
}

- (void)repeatCheckIfShouldHaptic {
    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:timeDelayInSeconds target:self selector:@selector(checkIfShouldHaptic) userInfo:nil repeats:NO];
}
```

My programming capabilities are pretty limited so I was wondering if someone could show me if and how this could be optimised?

I'm not sure if a function calling itself over and over is good practice or if there's a better way to repeat a check.
Thank you.

Comment: FYI - this kind of polling is probably a really bad idea. It would be much better to have some sort of event posted when the score changes.

Comment: @rmaddy Ideally yes, but I'm using a drag and drop game engine that only allows users to check the current score using a hook class they provide. So unfortunately I have to manually check score changes like this. Thanks for posting.

Comment: These methods are unlikely to impose any non-negligible performance problems. Have you observed any? They're fine as is. (Not perfect, but fine.)

Comment: Ok, thank you for posting. No, no performance issues observed so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would rewrite your code a little. IMHO Using NSTimer is more resources consuming operation then using GCD.
Your approach is not so bad if you don't have any other options to receive some sort of notification.

```
- (void)checkIfShouldHaptic {
  loadedScore = [self loadScoreFromKey:keyScore];          //load score saved in key
  controllerScore = [self checkCurrentScore];              //check current score

  if (loadedScore < controllerScore){                      //if score in key is less than controller score
    [self saveScore:controllerScore];                      //save new score in key
    AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(kSystemSoundID_Vibrate);  //play system sound
  }
  [self repeatCheckIfShouldHaptic];                      //repeat
}

- (void)repeatCheckIfShouldHaptic {
  __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
  dispatch_after(dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, (int64_t)(timeDelayInSeconds * NSEC_PER_SEC)), dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
    [weakSelf checkIfShouldHaptic]
  });
}
```

Comment: Ah, awesome! This definitely appears more efficient. Thank you.

Comment: The difference between a timer and `dispatch_after()` is immeasurably small;  irrelevantly so unless you are polling at hundreds of times a second, at which point there is an overarching design problem that should be addressed..   Use whichever API is most comfortable.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can use [KVO](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueObserving/KeyValueObserving.html)

```
@property NSUInteger score;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [self addObserver:self forKeyPath:@"score" options:NSKeyValueObservingOptionNew | NSKeyValueObservingOptionOld context:nil];
}

-(void)observeValueForKeyPath:(NSString *)keyPath ofObject:(id)object change:(NSDictionary *)change context:(void *)context
{
    NSLog(@"From KVO");

    if([keyPath isEqualToString:@"score"])
    {
        id oldScore = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeOldKey];
        id newScore = [change objectForKey:NSKeyValueChangeNewKey];

        NSLog(@"%@ %@", oldScore, newScore);
    }
}
```

Comment: That'd only work if `score` is an observable property.   Given OP's code, that is unlikely.  But a solution would be to make it KVO compliant!  Certainly, that'd be better than polling!